# Cannot install Twilio package with anaconda python3.6 on windows

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, twilio, conda

When I try to install Twilio  with conda on windows10 it gives me the following error:

```
>>> conda install -c jonrowland twilio
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.6*
  - twilio -> httplib2 -> python 2.7* -> vc 9
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I am using python 3.6 with Anaconda on Windows 10.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear... twilio is only available for Python 2.7

Comment: Twilio's Python library does work on Python 3.6. Why are you using the `jonrowland` channel for the Twilio package and not the `pypi` version?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

use pip3 install twilio

if you get an error about "TwilioRestClient has been removed from this version of the library. Please refer to current documentation for guidance." replace the "TwilioRestClient" with "Client"